# Error: GraphQL error: Cannot return null for non-nullable field Mutation.updateRendezvous

Tags: vue.js, graphql, edit

i try to update a field and i get this error Error: GraphQL error: Cannot return null for non-nullable field Mutation.updateRendezvous.
this is my update function

```
updateApp() {
      this.submitted = true;
      // stop here if form is invalid
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
      console.log('i am in form action')
         this.$store.dispatch("rendezvousModule/updateRendezvous", {
          details: this.Rendezvous.details,
          day: this.Rendezvous.day,
          start: this.Rendezvous.start,
          phone: Number(this.Rendezvous.phone),
          email: this.Rendezvous.email,
         
           
        }) .then(()=>{
        this.$router.push("bookings")})
        Swal.fire("Done!", "Appointment updated successfully!", "success");
         // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
         console.log('Appointment updated');

       
      }
```

and this is my updateMutation

```
UPDATE_RENDEZVOUS(state, payload) {
    console.log("payload", payload);
    const index = state.rendezvouss.findIndex(rendezvous => rendezvous._id === payload._id);
    console.log("index", index);
    Vue.set(state.rendezvouss, index, payload);
  },
```

and my updateActions µ

```
async updateRendezvous({ commit }, payload) {
    try {
      console.log('i am inside try update action')

      const { data } = await apolloClient.mutate({
        mutation: UPDATE_RENDEZVOUS,
        variables: payload
      });
      console.log("update Rendezvous", data.updateRendezvous);

      commit("UPDATE_RENDEZVOUS", data.updateRendezvous);
      commit("setLoading", false);
    } catch (error) {
      commit('setLoading', false)
      commit('setError', error)
      console.error(error);
    }
  },
```

the thing is this line  console.log("update Rendezvous", data.updateRendezvous); is not executed
i only get the outcome of this line console.log('i am inside try update action')
any suggestion will be appreciated
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the network request to the GraphQL API itself?

This actually sounds like a GraphQL API error that's being surfaced in your client-side application, which is what the code you posted referred to.

Specifically it sounds like your `Mutation.updateRendezvous` is returning a non-nullable result, e.g. `updateRendezvous: Rendezvous!`. In other words, it's looking like your GraphQL schema expects the `updateRendezvous` field to be non-nullable but your resolver in your executable schema may be returning `undefined` or `null`.

Comment: I tried testing it in the backend it WORKED but in the front in my mutation  i add a console and it didn't executed i think the problem is here                         UPDATE_RENDEZVOUS(state, payload) {
    console.log("payload", payload);
    const index = state.rendezvouss.findIndex(rendezvous => rendezvous._id === payload._id);
    console.log("index", index);
    Vue.set(state.rendezvouss, index, payload);
  },